# Calling Methods to Generate ASCII Art

Tags: java, loops, methods

To whomever reads this, I appreciate you taking your time to do so.

Essentially I am attempting to generate this exact ASCII art **by calling x amount of methods, I was thinking about 3 personally**:

```java
*          *
**        **
***      ***
****    ****
*****  *****
************
*****  *****
****    ****
***      ***
**        **
*          *
```

The first is to generate the upper portion, the second to generate the middle portion and the third to generate the last portion of asterisks.

I currently handle the drawing in a single method, and I need help breaking it up into multiple sections.

https://pastebin.com/RDE2KLHk

This paste-bin link has my current progress.

Thank you. I deeply appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you learned about parameters yet? Basically, you have a method that you call to draw the entire image. The image can be drawn in 2 parts, the top half and the bottom half. You do not need a middle section, as it can be covered in the loop in either the top half or the bottom half. If you want a method to draw the middle, you can write that yourself and adjust the for loops.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // pass in the height of the triangles
    // in your example it's 6
    printImage(6);
}

public static void printImage(int height) {
    printTop(height);
    printBottom(height);
}

//also draws the middle part
public static void printBottom(int height) {
    for (int i = height; i > 0; i--) {
        printStar(i);
        printSpace(2 * (height - i));
        printStar(i);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void printTop(int height) {
    for (int i = 1; i < height; i++) {
        printStar(i);
        printSpace(2 * (height - i));
        printStar(i);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void printStar(int stars) {
    for (int i = 0; i < stars; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}

public static void printSpace(int spaces) {
    for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

Your methods can also take more than one parameter as well. Notice that printTop and printBottom have basically the same code. This is bad. To reduce redundancy, we can write another method.

```
public static void printLine(int stars, int spaces) {
    printStar(i);
    printSpace(spaces);
    printSTar(i);
}
```

Then, inside the printTop and printBottom methods, you can call it like so:

```
printLine(i, 2 * (height - i));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look more into methods and arguments!

Comment: @MathewRomano I actually just edited it to draw the top and bottom as you asked in your question :)